# Parsing X509 Certificate Bundles in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, regex, parsing, x509

I am trying to parse a x509 certificate bundle which is a pem file consisting of multiple certificates in the following format:

```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   xxxx
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    xxxx
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   xxxx
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I am able to read and parse a single certificate pem file using jsrsasign X509 library like so:

```
    import r from "jsrsasign";
      const cert = new r.X509();
      cert.readCertPEM(input);
      issuer = cert.getIssuerString();
```

I need to parse the certificate bundles in a similar fashion. How can I do it ? I am using Nodejs.
I tried using Regular Expressions to extract individual certificates as strings and pass it to cert.readCertPEM(input) in a loop. But I was not able to figure out the proper RE to do so. 
If using RE is the way to go, then can I please know how I can do it.

Thanks.

Comment: `input.split('-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youcould match the begin certificate part, then capture in a group matching all lines that do not start with `-----` using a negative lookahead `(?!-----)` and after that match the end certificate part.

```
^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r?\n((?:(?!-----).*\r?\n)*)-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3xMJNl/1)

```js
const regex = /^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r?\n((?:(?!-----).*\r?\n)*)-----END CERTIFICATE-----/gm;
const str = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  console.log(m[1]);
}
```